# 'tigerstats' package giving error while loading

Tags: r

When I run the command `library(tigerstats)`, I am getting an error:

```
library(tigerstats) 
Loading required package: abd 
Loading required package: nlme 
Loading required package: lattice 
Loading required package: grid 
Loading required package: mosaic 
Loading required package: dplyr 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’ Error: package ‘dplyr’ could not be loaded
```

Please help.

Comment: Seems like you are missing some packages or they are not installed in the right place for this to run. Have you confirmed you have the dependencies installed?

Comment: Your error supplies the answer. You do not have the package "Rcpp" installed. Check that you have that installed, and then check that you also have "dplyr".

Comment: The question was not very well formated and had some minor issues with the English language used. But the real problem is that the question shouldn't have been asked in the first place since its error message gives all information needed to solve the problem, like noted in the comments.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you for correcting my post. This was my question ever. And special thanks to @ E.O who helped me solve this problem. Man, you were right. There were a couple of packages to be installed first in order to run tigerstats successfully.